# No temperature reading on Ryzen 5700G?

Tags: kernel-modules, amd, sensors

I've built a new computer with a AMD Ryzen 5700G and to my surprise, no sensor information is picked up whatsoever. I thought perhaps the new AMD chips would not yet be recognized by Linux, but the docs say otherwise.

Here's `sudo sensors-detect`:

```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0+git
# System: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B550I AORUS PRO AX [Default string]
# Kernel: 5.14.6-arch1-1 x86_64
# Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with Radeon Graphics (25/80/0)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
AMD Family 19h thermal sensors...                           No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No
```

The kernel version should be new enough, and the 5700G should be detected as 'AMD Family 19h', but clearly it isn't.

I've tried manually loading the `k10temp` module to no effect. I've also tried reinstalling `lm_sensors`, updating the system and installing the 3rd party utility 'Zenpower', but still `sensors` looks quite pathetic:

```
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +16.8°C  (crit = +20.8°C)

nvme-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +43.9°C
```

Is it perhaps the Zen 3 APU's that can't be detected? Or is there some other module or setting I'm missing?

Comment: it should work with 5.15 kernel

Comment: [AMD Zen 3 APU Temperature Monitoring Narrowly Misses Linux 5.14](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Zen-3-APU-Temp-hwmon)

Comment: @frostschutz thanks! That link should've popped up in Google, either it wasn't ranked highly enough or my keywords didn't match that well. I had the suspicion it was just the APU's, but it seemed a bit trivial given they're Zen 3 too and chips like the 5600X are reporting just fine. Turns out it was trivial after all :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The driver in Linux 5.14 doesn't support these APUs yet, it will be available in 5.15 but you can grab it now and compile in 5.14 (must be safe).

Comment: I tried Zenpower3, that gives me clock speeds (the Zenmonitor) but no temps. Also, it seems the last real update was from June 2020.

Comment: Sorry, removed it from my answer. It's all quite sad really.

Comment: I am on 5.15.0-48-generic and am having this same issue :/

Comment: This kernel release has long been unsupported, please `sudo dnf update` and reboot.